# Warum ist es "tagesthemen" und nicht "Tagesthemen"

Tags: word-usage, capitalization

Warum heißt die Fernsehsendung "tagesthemen" und nicht "Tagesthemen" großgeschrieben?

Comment: Just fancy design!

Comment: Im Videotext (ARD, Seite 303) heißt es korrekt "Tagesthemen". Man kann aber keinem Sender verbieten sein Produkt blödsinnig zu benennen. Kleingeschrieben soll es vielleicht die Seriosität der Kargheit eines Fernschreibers transportieren, der aus Kostengründen nur mit Kleinbuchstaben arbeitete (wobei ich nicht weiß, ob es da jemals gab), oder US-Flair verbreiten, obwohl ja Eigennamen im englischen Sprachraum auch oft groß geschrieben werden, wenn die Designer nicht anderes gepredigt haben.

Comment: Warum die *taz*? Darum.

Comment: `<cite style="text-transform: lowercase;">Tagesthemen</cite>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Kleinschreibung ist nur im Logo der Sendung wiederzufinden, in der schriftlichen Kommunikation wird auch von der ARD immer die "normale" Schreibweise mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben genutzt.

Dasselbe Prinzip findet sich im Übrigen auch beim [Nachtmagazin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachtmagazin) und bei der [Tagesschau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagesschau_(ARD)), bei denen die Schrift im Logo nur aus Kleinbuchstaben besteht.

Das Logo der Tagesschau besteht dabei schon seit 1956 aus Kleinbuchstaben. Evtl. fiel die Entscheidung für diesen Schriftzug, um das neue Format auch optisch mehr von den Wochenschauen im Kino (deren Logo nur aus Großbuchstaben bestand) abzugrenzen.
[image]
Quelle: [tagesschau.de](https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/bilder/tagesschau210.html)

Für die neueren Tagesthemen wurde das Logo genauso wie das Logo der Tagesschau gestaltet, um eine schnelle Wiedererkennbarkeit zu gewährleisten und ggf. auch um den guten Ruf der Tagesschau zu nutzen. Heutzutage macht die Kleinschreibung auch die Verbindung zu den digitalen Angeboten einfacher, da Domains i.d.R. klein geschrieben werden.

Comment: Domains sind aber groß/klein-agnostisch, d.h. man kann sie ohne Beeinträchtigung auch groß schreiben. Kleinschreibung macht hier nichts einfacher.